How can I achieve absolute positioning on a flex element?
I created following component
<!-- AppBar.vue -->
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn text="Our plans"></v-btn>
  </v-row>
</template>

and when used it looks like this

But when I change its position to be absolute like this
<div
  style="background-color: burlywood"
  class="h-screen"
>
  <v-container class="fill-height position-relative">
    <AppBar class="position-absolute top-0" />
  </v-container>
</div>

it is rendered like this

What am I doing wrong?
Why do I need to use absolute positioning on the app bar?
Because I have an image with vertically centered content inside of it and the app bar always on top, like this


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Why do you need to position absolutely?

@Paulie_D I don't really understand your first comment since this is my usual way of asking questions here and nobody really complained. Anyway, I edited the question, hope it helps

Please don't get hung up on being asked for a repo. It's actually a very common ask on this site and extremely helpful for those wanting to help debug issues.  you can provide demo link like this

I'm also not fully understanding the expected result.  top: 0 positions the app bar at the very top of the relative positioned parent.  The result then is technically correct...  Do you mean you want the "Our Plans" button to remain on the right-hand side?  Does width: 100% on v-row accomplish what you want?

Absolutely positioned elements are removed from normal flow layout, and any space they would have taken up is removed.  v-row will require width: 100% to return to "normal"
